# When should I worry about alignment?

Tags: c++

I've learned a little about alignment recently but I am not certain in which situations it will be an issue or not. There are two cases that I wonder about:

The first one is when using arrays:

```
struct Foo {
    char data[3]; // size is 3, my arch is 64-bit (8 bytes)
};

Foo array[4]; // total memory is 3 * 4 = 12 bytes. 
              // will this be padded to 16?

void testArray() {
    Foo foo1 = array[0];
    Foo foo2 = array[1]; // is foo2 pointing to a non-aligned location?
                           // should one expect issues here?
}
```

The second case is when using a memory pool:

```
struct Pool {
    Pool(std::size_t size = 256) : data(size), used(0), freed(0) { }

    template<class T>
    T * allocate() {
        T * result = reinterpret_cast<T*>(&data[used]);
        used += sizeof(T);
        return result;
    }

    template<class T>
    void deallocate(T * ptr) {
        freed += sizeof(T);
        if (freed == used) {
            used = freed = 0;
        }
    }

    std::vector<char> data;
    std::size_t used;
    std::size_t freed;
};

void testPool() {
    Pool pool;
    Foo * foo1 = pool.allocate<Foo>(); // points to data[0]
    Foo * foo2 = pool.allocate<Foo>(); // points to data[3],
                                       // alignment issue here?
    pool.deallocate(foo2);
    pool.deallocate(foo1);
}
```

My questions are:

- Are there any alignment issues in the two code samples?
- If yes, then how can they be fixed?
- Where can I learn more about this?

#### Update

I am using a 64-bit Intel i7 processor with Darwin GCC.
But I also use Linux, Windows (VC2008) for 32-bit and 64-bit systems.

#### Update 2

Pool now uses a vector instead of array.

Comment: Depends on the processor and the compiler.  What are you using?  If it's an ARM, DEFINITELY!

Comment: `Foo foo1 = array[0];` instead of  `Foo * foo1 = array[0];` etc. according to VS10 C90. Edit it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
struct Foo {
    char data[3]; // size is 3, my arch is 64-bit (8 bytes)
};
```

Padding *is* allowed here, in the struct after the `data` member--but not before it, and not between the elements of `data`.

```
Foo array[4]; // total memory is 3 * 4 = 12 bytes.
```

No padding is allowed between elements in the array here. Arrays are required to be contiguous. But, as noted above, padding is allowed inside of a `Foo`, following its `data` member. So, `sizeof(someFoo.data)` must be 3, but `sizeof(someFoo)` could be (and often will be 4).

```
void testArray() {
    Foo * foo1 = array[0];
    Foo * foo2 = array[1]; // is foo2 pointing to a non-aligned location?
                           // should I expect issues here?
}
```

Again, perfectly fine -- the compiler must allow this<sup>1</sup>.

For your memory pool, the prognosis isn't nearly as good though. You've allocated an array of `char`, which has to be sufficiently aligned to be accessed as `char`, but accessing it as any other type is *not* guaranteed to work. The implementation isn't allowed to impose any alignment limits on accessing data as `char` in any case though.

Typically for a situation like this, you create a union of all the types you care about, and allocate an array of that. This guarantees that the data is aligned to be used as an object of any type in the union.

Alternatively, you can allocate your block dynamically -- both `malloc` and `operator ::new` guarantee that any block of memory is aligned to be used as any type.

Edit: changing the pool to use `vector<char>` improves the situation, but only slightly. It means the *first* object you allocate will work because the block of memory held by the vector will be allocated (indirectly) with `operator ::new` (since you haven't specified otherwise). Unfortunately, that doesn't help much -- the second allocation may be completely misaligned.

For example, let's assume each type requires "natural" alignment -- i.e., alignment to a boundary equal to its own size. A char can be allocated at any address. We'll assume short is 2 bytes, and requires an even address and int and long are 4 bytes and require 4-byte alignment.

In this case, consider what happens if you do:

```
char *a = Foo.Allocate<char>();
long *b = Foo.Allocate<long>();
```

The block we started with had to be aligned for any type, so it was definitely an even address. When we allocate the `char`, we use up only one byte, so the next available address is odd. We then allocate enough space for a `long`, but it's at an odd address, so attempting to dereference it gives UB.

---

<sup>1</sup> Mostly anyway -- ultimately, a compiler can reject just about anything under the guise of an implementation limit having been exceeded. I'd be surprised to see a real compiler have a problem with this though.

Comment: There's also `aligned_storage` in C++0x, with the fitting `alignof` operator or meta function (don't remember which exactly).

Comment: @Xeo: Yup -- and pretty much what he needs in this case.

Comment: `No padding is allowed here. Arrays are required to be contiguous.` Yes, but `Foo` could be padded.

Comment: @Martin: How? If the array is contiguous, and there is no second member, how can there be any padding?

Comment: For the first example, the compiler may pad Foo to be aligned to some boundary (eg word, dependent on compiler switches). sizeof (Foo::data) will be 3 but sizeof(struct Foo) most likely will not be 3.

Comment: @Xeo: Because structures can be padded. The array not pad between members but the compiler may pad the structure to make the array members align to a particular boundary.

Comment: @Martin, @Xeo: I've added a bit more to the answer that (I hope) clarifies the situation a bit.

Comment: @Jerry: What reasons could a compiler have to pad `Foo` if it only contains a single (non-union) member?

Comment: @Xeo: It doesn't have to (since you could create an array of those items without them being in an array, it *must* be able to access them without padding). Nonetheless, it might decide to pad them anyway -- in the case of your 3-byte array, padding to 4 bytes lets it load an entire struct in a single instruction.

Answer (score 4):

Nobody has mentioned the memory pool yet. This has huge alignment problems.

```
T * result = reinterpret_cast<T*>(&data[used]);
```

That is no good. When you take over memory management, you need to take over **all** of the aspects of memory management, not just allocation. While you may have allocated the right amount of memory, you have not addressed alignment at all.

Suppose you use `new` or `malloc` to allocate one byte. Print it's address. Do this again, and print this new address:

```
char * addr1 = new char;
std::cout << "Address #1 = " << (void*) addr1 << "\n";
char * addr2 = new char;
std::cout << "Address #2 = " << (void*) addr2 << "\n";
```

On a 64 bit machine such as your Mac you will see that both of the printed addresses end with a zero and they are typically 16 bytes apart. You haven't allocated two bytes here. You have allocated 32! That's because `malloc` always returns a pointer that is aligned such that it can be used for *any* data type.

Put a double or a long long int on an address that does not end with 8 or 0 when printed in hex and you are likely to get a core dump. Doubles and long long ints need to be aligned to 8 byte boundaries. Similar constraints apply to plain old vanilla integers (int32_t); these need to be aligned on 4 byte boundaries. Your memory pool is not doing this.

Comment: +1, although your current rep is 1337 which is awesome, and one might note that integer misalignment on x86 may cause performance degradation, but not an address exception.

Answer (score 3):

Generally—that is, for most data structures—don't worry about alignment in advance.  The compiler will generally do the right thing.  The days of sweating time penalties for unaligned data are at least 20 years behind us.

The only issues remaining are illegal unaligned data access which occur only on a minority of CPU architectures.  Write the code so it makes sense.  Test it.  If an unaligned data exception occurs, then it is time to figure out how to avoid it.  Most cases are easily fixed by adding a command line option.  A few require altering the structure:  reordering elements, or explicitly inserting unused padding elements.

Comment: There are a few exceptions, some of which are widely used. ARM for example: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka3721.html. As a matter of fact, the X86 architecture is probably in the minority in this respect.

Comment: I am currently working on an embedded ARM project:  I go for months at a time without thinking about alignment.  Mostly, I prototype and debug/test on my x86 desktop.  Once it is good to go, I cross compile from the same place and run it on ARM.  Only once have I been bitten, and that was no big deal to fix.

Comment: I'm not saying the compiler doesn't hide alignment. I'm just saying that many architectures are sensitive to it.

Comment: There are other reasons to be concerned about alignment other than performance. When committing a structure like this to some form of storage, eg, a binary file, care must be taken to understand the alignment of all data members within the structure so that it can be read reliably.

Answer (score 3):

The alignment is handled transparently by the compiler - sizeof and array accesses always account for any alignment and you don't have to care about it.

There's a bug in the memory pool example though - if you call deallocate(), it always deallocates the last allocated pointer instead of the given pointer.