# Do I really have to worry about alignment when using placement new operator?

Tags: c++, g++, memory-alignment, powerpc, placement-new

I read this  [When should I worry about alignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474316/when-should-i-worry-about-alignment) but I am still do not know if I have to worry about not aligned pointer returned by placement new operator - like in this example:

```
class A {
public:
   long double a;
   long long b;
   A() : a(1.3), b(1234) {}
};

char buffer[64];

int main() {
   // (buffer + 1) used intentionally to have wrong alignment
   A* a = new (buffer + 1) A(); 
   a->~A();
}
```

`__alignof(A) == 4`, `(buffer + 1)` is not aligned to `4`. But everything works fine - full example here: http://ideone.com/jBrk8

If this depends on architecture then I am using: linux/powerpc/g++ 4.x.x.

[UPDATE] Just after posting this question I read this article: http://virtrev.blogspot.de/2010/09/memory-alignment-theory-and-c-examples.html.
Maybe the only drawbacks in my case would be performance penalty, I mean unaligned access cost more than aligned?

Comment: x86 is particularly forgiving of alignment issues, powerpc not so much.

Comment: Placement new just returns the pointer as given.

Comment: Unaligned accesses are often *supported but slow*. That's the case for x86, but I don't know for PPC.

Comment: @FatalError, with today's cache architectures I'm not sure that's true anymore. Certainly you'll see a hit if you cross a cache line boundary.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, it also calls the constructor which in this case is setting some members. If there's a problem it *should* trigger it.

Comment: IIRC, on PowerPC, unaligned integer loads are handled slowly by the processor, unaligned floating-point loads (or just doubles?) are normally handled by the OS, and unaligned vector loads give you a bus error. I also note that buffer+1 is not guaranteed to be misaligned because buffer is not guaranteed to be aligned.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When you call placement new on a buffer:

```
A *a = new (buf) A;
```

you are invoking the built-in `void* operator new (std::size_t size, void* ptr) noexcept` as defined in:

> [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)
>
> #### 18.6.1.3 Placement forms [new.delete.placement]
>
> These functions are reserved, a C++ program may not deﬁne functions that displace the versions in the
>   Standard C++ library (17.6.4). The provisions of (3.7.4) do not apply to these reserved placement forms of
>   operator new and operator delete.
>     `void* operator new(std::size_t size, void* ptr) noexcept;`
>   Returns: `ptr`.
>   Remarks: Intentionally performs no other action.

The *provisions of (3.7.4)* include that the returned pointer should be suitably aligned, so it's fine for `void* operator new (std::size_t size, void* ptr) noexcept` to return a nonaligned pointer if one is passed in.  This doesn't let *you* off the hook, though:

> #### 5.3.4 New [expr.new]
>
> [14] Note: when the allocation function returns a value other than null, it must be a pointer to a block of storage
>   in which space for the object has been reserved. The block of storage is assumed to be appropriately aligned
>   and of the requested size.

So if you pass unaligned storage to a placement-new expression you're violating the assumption that the storage is aligned, and the result is UB.

---

Indeed, in your program above, if you replace `long long b` with `__m128 b` (after `#include <xmmintrin.h>`) then the program will segfault, as expected.

Comment: so what does this mean? does this mean that we have to pass to the placement new address buffer + offset, where (buffer + offset) % alignment of the class == 0 ?

Comment: @bysreg sure, that would work, as long as you ensure that the space remaining is sufficient. Or you could use a facility providing a buffer that is already aligned, such as aligned_storage or posix_memalign.

Answer (score 13):

Just because everything appears to work doesn't mean it *actually* does.

C++ is a specification that defines what is *required* to work. The compiler can also make not required things work. That's what "undefined behavior" means: anything can happen, so your code isn't portable anymore.

C++ does not *require* this to work. So if you take your code to a compiler where this doesn't work, you can't blame C++ anymore; it's your fault for misusing the language.

Comment: Do you mean that using not aligned pointer in placement new is UB? Can you clarify which standard says that: C++03 or C++11?

Comment: C++11 § 3.11\2 "Object types have alignment requirements (3.9.1, 3.9.2) which place restrictions on the addresses at which an
object of that type may be allocated." and § 3.11\8 "If a request for a specific extended alignment in a specific context is not supported by an implementation,
the program is ill-formed. Additionally, a request for runtime allocation of dynamic storage for which the requested alignment cannot be honored shall be treated as an allocation failure."

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it all depends on the architecture, and probably the compiler optimization flags as well.
It will all work fine until you do `A b = a;` or some other random access which gets compiled to some [`movdqa`](http://www.jaist.ac.jp/iscenter-new/mpc/altix/altixdata/opt/intel/vtune/doc/users_guide/mergedProjects/analyzer_ec/mergedProjects/reference_olh/mergedProjects/instructions/instruct32_hh/vc183.htm) ops and your program crashes.

Answer (score 4):

some processors will definitely blow up with this (sparc for example), others will not care at all, others will be slow. C++ is assuming that you know what you are doing (or not), same as reinterpret_cast etc.

Answer (score 3):

a quick google tells me that gcc on powerpc has an option to tell the compiler if unaligned accesses are handeled by the system or not.

I would assume that in either case unaligned accesses on that platform will be very slow, and should be avoided as much as possible.