# What is the difference between struct __declspec(align(16)) sse_t and struct alignas(16) sse_t?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-alignment

What is the difference between `struct __declspec(align(16)) sse_t{};` and `struct alignas(16) sse_t{};`?

Link to an example of the alignment of structures in C++11: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas

```
// every object of type sse_t will be aligned to 16-byte boundary
struct alignas(16) sse_t
{
  float sse_data[4];
};

// the array "cacheline" will be aligned to 128-byte boundary
alignas(128) char cacheline[128];
```

However, there is not in MSVS2012 keyword `alignas(16)`, but you can use `__declspec(align(16))`: [Where can I use alignas() in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15788947/where-can-i-use-alignas-in-c11)
What we can see in example:

```
#include <iostream>

#ifdef __GNUC__
struct __attribute__(align(16)) sse_t
#else
struct __declspec(align(16)) sse_t
#endif
{
  float sse_data[4];
};

/*
// Why doesn't it support in MSVS 2012 if it is the same as __declspec(align(16)) ?
struct alignas(16) sse_t
{
  float sse_data[4];
};
*/    

int main() {
    // aligned data
    sse_t ab;
    ab.sse_data[1] = 10;

    // what will happen?
    unsigned char *buff_ptr = new unsigned char [1000]; // allocate buffer
    sse_t * unaligned_ptr = new(buff_ptr + 3) sse_t;    // placement new
    unaligned_ptr->sse_data[1] = 20;    

    int b; std::cin >> b;
    return 0;
}
```

1. These functionalities of alignment are equivalent?
2. And if so - equivalent, why did not entered keyword `alignas()` in MSVS2012, because this functionality is already there `__declspec(align(16))`?
3. And what will happen if such a structure to place on a misaligned address through "placement new": `new(buff_ptr + 3)`?

Comment: `alignas` is the standard-conforming version of either `__attribute__(align(..))` or `__declspec(align(..))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. To my knowledge they are equivalent, the difference being that `struct alignas(16) sse_t{};` is standard C++ and `struct __declspec(align(16)) sse_t{};` is a pre-C++11 Microsoft extension.
2. Microsoft hadn't gotten around to implementing `alignas()` in their compiler in MSVS2012, you'd have to ask them why. <s>IIRC it is supported in MSVS2013.</s> EDIT: I'm a liar, [MSVS2013 still does not support `alignas` / `alignof`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx).
3. Horrible things will likely happen if such a structure is misaligned. You don't even need placement `new` to do so, plain old `new` is oblivious to alignment requirements beyond those needed for primitive types as of C++11.

Comment: Point (3) there's a question exactly about that - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781724/do-i-really-have-to-worry-about-alignment-when-using-placement-new-operator

Comment: Thanks! (2), but may be some difference which motivate to doesn't implement alignas() in MSVS2013? And (3), have said here about **Plain old new** http://stackoverflow.com/a/11782277/1558037 and in C++03-Standard "5.3.4 New  14 [Note: when the allocation function returns a value other than null, it must be a pointer to a block of storage in which space for the object has been reserved. The **block of storage is assumed to be appropriately aligned** and of the requested size. The address of the created object will not necessarily be the same as that
of the block if the object is an array. ]".

Comment: @Casey Different between `__declspec(align())` and `alignas()` in that - `alignas()` in C++11-standard requires to throw an exception `std::bad_alloc()` when operator `new`/`new[]` can't place objects with this alignment, isn't it? http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2341.pdf