# On the use of alignas in C++17 and its relation to Visual Studio/MVC++'s _declspec(align(...))

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, c++17

In order to ensure a user-specified memory alignment of certain data structures in C++, I think three use cases need to be taken care off and dealt with appropriately (*if I am missing some use cases, feel free to add them*):

1. static memory allocation;
2. dynamic memory allocation;
3. memory allocation in containers (e.g. `std::vector`) and smart pointers (e.g. `std::shared_ptr`).

C++11 takes care of the static memory allocation by adding the `alignas` specifier which allows to manually specify the alignment. C++17 takes care of the dynamic memory allocation by implicitly overriding `operator new`, `operator new[]`, `operator delete` and `operator delete[]`. Though, I noticed that C++17 added overloads of these operators with an extra alignment parameter as well?

Containers like `std::vector` can allocate a large block of raw memory for storing the container elements. The container elements can then be allocated by passing a pointer to some location in this block to `operator new` (placement new). There is a similar situation for `std::shared_ptr` which uses a control and data block that are allocated together in case `std::make_shared` is called (*which is different for `std::unique_ptr` which only uses a data block, which will be allocated with `operator new` after calling `std::make_unique`*). In order to ensure the correct memory alignment for container elements and the data block of `std::shared_ptr`, the `std` provides the possibility to pass an [allocator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator) which will be used for these allocations. Given that `alignas` is specified for some data structure, is it still necessary to pass such an allocator to ensure the correct memory alignment in C++17? Or is this handled internally by `std::vector`, `std::shared_ptr`, etc. (by using `alignof`)?

Visual Studio (which is closely connected to the MVC++ compiler) supports the `alignas` and `alignof` keywords since Visual Studio 2015. Because some Microsoft libraries are still maintained for Visual Studio 2013, the use of `_declspec(align(...))` is ubiquitous. `_declspec(align(...))` only takes care of the static memory allocation. To handle dynamic memory allocation, one typically publically inherit from the following stateless structure:

```
template< typename TDerived >
struct AlignedNew {

    static void* operator new (size_t size) {
        const size_t alignment = __alignof(TDerived);

        static_assert(alignment > 8);

        void* ptr = _aligned_malloc(size, alignment);

        if (!ptr)
            throw std::bad_alloc();

        return ptr;
    }

    static void operator delete (void* ptr) {
        _aligned_free(ptr);
    }

    static void* operator new[] (size_t size) {
        return operator new(size);
    }

    static void operator delete[] (void* ptr) {
        operator delete(ptr);
    }
};
```

So I wonder if the combination of `_declspec(align(...))` + inheriting this struct and `alignas(...)` provides the same functionality or if `alignas(...)` provides the same but even more functionality than `_declspec(align(...))` + inheriting this struct? And if this is the case, can I safely replace the `_declspec(align(...))` with `alignas(...)` and remove the `AlignedNew` structure?

Their is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19958912/what-is-the-difference-between-struct-declspecalign16-sse-t-and-struct-ali) about this last part from the pre-C++17 era, but the first dot of the accepted and only answer is not very profound, imho.

Note that multiple C++ standards are mentioned in this question and multiple MVC++ versions which are only partial implementations of various of these C++ standards. I am mostly concerned with C++17 (and the [latest iteration of Visual Studio 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/visual-cpp-language-conformance))