# Dynamic (type) binary buffer in C++?

Tags: c++, stl

Currently, I'm using `std::vector<char>` like this:

```
char data, data2, data3;

vec.push_back(data);
vec.push_back(data2);
vec.push_back(data3);
```

However, since I'm storing binary data, sometimes I need to push data of different sizes (i.e. not a single char), and I need to manually split that data into single bytes, which is not convenient or readable.

Something like this would be perfect:

```
buffer.push<int>(some_int); // some_int = 0xAABBCCDD
buffer.push<char>(some_char); // some_char = 0xFF
buffer.push("arbitrary_data", arbitrary_length);
```

The resulting memory would be:

```
AA BB CC DD FF ...........
// ^ int
//          ^ char
```

Is there any standard way of doing it, or I need libraries / own implementation?

Comment: While this is not the best way to go about it, you can always use `std::vector<void*>`.

Comment: You could use a vector of unsigned char, resize it whenever you need a new item, and construct that type in the array.

Comment: There's no standard way for this. `boost::any` is handy for something like what you're trying to do.

Comment: Did you looked to [MessagePack](http://msgpack.org/) ? It could serialize int, string or structure, then you could add it to an `std::vector<std::string>`

Comment: @JamesRoot: Except that the location would likely be unaligned.

Comment: @MSalters how do you align a single-byte vector? without wasting 3 bytes per byte, that is

Comment: @AcidShout: You don't. Which is why James's comment and KemyLand's answer are wrong. BTW, don't assume that alignment is always to 4 bytes. Check `alignof(T)`. On a related note, don't assume endianness either. You may very well get `0xDD 0xCC 0xBB 0xAA` after pushing `0xAABBCCDD`.

Comment: Without knowing your use-case, it feels like you might want to use `stringstream` instead of `vector`.

Comment: @MSalters @Hurkyl I'm working with a propietary file format, which is like `[byte][byte][byte][byte][2 bytes][2 bytes][null-terminated string][byte][4 bytes]`... which is why I need something like this (i.e. alignment would break the format)

Comment: @AcidShout: That is a valid file format, but probably a valid format for objects in memory. Not a big deal, though, you can memcpy all the values into the `std::vector`. Don't forget `htonl`/`htons` or other endian-fixing functions!

Comment: @MSalters yeah, I see, but how do I properly align that? Or it just can't be aligned and that's it?

Comment: I just wrote something similar to the accepted answer that has aligned access at the cost of speed (ironically).

Comment: @JamesRoot is it worth it?

Comment: Actually I can probably rewrite some of it to mitigate the speed. It just has to keep track of padding in between values so that it can put on the facade of a normal vector. For example `for (int i = 0; i < aligned.size(); ++i) std::cout << aligned[i];` would print like a normal vector or array, even if there was padding between every value you tried to access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this? It works even for non-POD types! (Note: C++11 code!)

```
#include <new>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

class BinaryVector : public std::vector<unsigned char> {
    public:
        template<typename T>
        void push(const T &what) {
            this->resize(this->size() + sizeof(T));
            new(this->data() + this->size() - sizeof(T)) T(what);
        }

        template<typename T>
        void push(T &&what) {
            this->resize(this->size() + sizeof(T));
            new((T*)(this->data() + this->size() - sizeof(T))) T(XValue(what));
        }

        template<typename T>
        T pop() {
            T tmp(std::move(*(T*)(this->data() + this->size() - sizeof(T))));
            ((T*)(this->data() + this->size() - sizeof(T)))->~T();
            this->resize(this->size - sizeof(T));

            return tmp;
        }
};
```

Comment: Creating new objects without allocating memory yourself, and letting the vector handle it instead. Genius!

Comment: Be careful with memory alignment ! [Do I really have to worry about alignment when using placement new operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11782277/1743220) -> Yes

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is called serialization, and it's not part of the ISO standard. Boost does have a library for it, though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use pointer arithmetic in combine with `reinterpret_cast` like the example bellow:

```
std::vector<char> v;
v.push_back('a');
v.push_back('b');
int a = 20;
v.insert(v.end(), reinterpret_cast<char*>(&a), reinterpret_cast<char*>(&a) + sizeof(a));
```

or if you have a class/struct:

```
struct foo {int a = 1 , b = 2, c = 3;};

std::vector<char> v;
foo b;
v.insert(v.end(), reinterpret_cast<char*>(&b), reinterpret_cast<char*>(&b) + sizeof(b));
```