# Is reinterpret_cast-ing a memory buffer back and forth safe, and is the alignas necessary in placement new context?

Tags: c++, reinterpret-cast, placement-new

While the title might not be very specific, it refers to the general understanding on how much we can play with `reinterpret_cast<>()` while dealing with memory buffers. Considering the following code:

```
struct foo { };

int main() {
    auto buffer = reinterpret_cast<foo*>(new char[3 * sizeof(foo)]);

    new (buffer) foo;
    new (buffer + 1) foo;

    std::destroy(buffer, buffer + 2);

    delete[] reinterpret_cast<char*>(buffer);
}
```

I asked myself a question - *is this safe **and** correct?*

When searching various sources of information, I encountered a lot of examples that used `alignas`. As it can be seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781724/do-i-really-have-to-worry-about-alignment-when-using-placement-new-operator), (at to least my understanding), the problem of not aligning was caused by a specific offset of the memory buffer pointer. If my understading is incorrect, please correct me.

The question itself is - *Does this code safely mimicks the memory buffer of, let's say, `std::vector<foo>`?* What does it lack? Is the `alignas` required here? Where would I apply it? How to minimally construct an example of what vector does in this case?

Comment: `new` should give you a pointer which has the alignment which can hold any fundamental type, so there's no need of `alignas` anywhere in your example. But your example will have problems, when you index `buffer`, because there's no array of `foo`s there, just `foo`'s placed next to each other. C++ differentiates between these cases. With current C++, it's impossible to rewrite `std::vector`, which is kind of funny...

Comment: I'm positive the answer is "no", because although they're contiguous, they don't form an array such that iterating from `buffer` to `buffer + 2` works. Can't dive into the standard right now though, but you'll find that coming up in the discussions about how to implement `std::vector` without UB.

Comment: @geza can you elaborate on the unimplementability of `std::vector`? I've seen a discussion somewhere, but can't manage to find it. **@downvoter**, care to explain? How can I improve my question?

Comment: @geza `new` is going to give the OP memory alligned for a `char`.  If `foo` doesn't have the same alignment then that can be an issue.

Comment: @NathanOliver could you please provide some source of examples where can I learn how to determinate whether the alignments check out?

Comment: @NathanOliver: maybe, I'm not sure. OP should call operator new (instead of new expression), and then it surely won't be a problem.

Comment: @NathanOliver that question and answer completely satisfy me. Thank you for finding the duplicate. I would still love to wait for the mentioned discussion about the unimplementability of `std::vector` though

Comment: @Fureeish It was a comment on the top answer.  It links to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48062346/is-a-pointer-with-the-right-address-and-type-still-always-a-valid-pointer-since/48065437#comment83125977_48065437)

Comment: @Fureeish: I don't remember any specific question about this. But surely this has been discussed here. Maybe just tangentially (it came up because of something else, and discussed in comments). Do a search, and if you don't find a question about it, please put a question :) Because I think it worth a separate question, and not just some comments.

Comment: @Fureeish: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52996590/implementing-a-stdvector-like-container-without-undefined-behavior

Comment: @Fureeish: btw., maybe it's the case that `std::vector` can be implemented without UB. But the solution would depend on implementation-defined behavior, for sure. I know two problematic things: array placement new (which could have implementation-defined overhead), and pointer arithmetic (can be circumvented by reinterpret_casting to integer, do the artithmetic there, and reinterpret_cast back - this is implementation defined)

Comment: @Fureeish: ah, forget it, I think it has definitely UB. Objects need to be created one-by-one (I mean, to support `push_back`). So the array cannot be created by array placement new. Each element need to created separately, so strictly speaking, it won't be a proper array.